# I am trying to send email through smtp but an error is showing

Tags: php

I am trying to send email through `SMTP` but an error is showing

> 2015-08-13 07:03:50   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) The following From address failed: bijay009009@gmail.com Mailer Error: The following From address failed: bijay009009@gmail.com

Comment: [Show code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Not all people are farseeing. And to avoid getting frustrating comments, I suggest you to read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 'Luck.

Answer (score 0):

There can be few reasons for the error:
1. The email server is unreachable. Either the server is down or email service is not running or your fiewall is blocking the access.
2. The user does not have permission to connect to the server to send email using SMTP.

Comment: try to ping to the server or try telnet. If both works you can ask the email server admin to find out whether the user is having SMTP permission or not.